# Is there any way to update woocommerce inventory with external web based system?

Tags: woocommerce, rest, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there any way to update woocommerce product inventory with external web based system, such as warehose system? And send json data yo that system? In fact make interaction between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce has inventory management functionality, and a external system use it via the
[REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction).

If you look at a specific product, there's an "Inventory" tab.  If "Manage stock" is checked, you can, well, manage the stock, ie. manage the stock quantity, allow backorders, receive emails notifications when stock is low.

This can be done manually, or via the create/update [Products](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product) or [Product variations](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product-variation) endpoints.  Without modification, to make the calls, this requires your external system to know the WooCommerce product & product variation ID's (for my employer, I built a layer on top of the REST API that works with product SKU's, which are know by our external system).

To make actual calls, you'll need to [generate a key & secret in WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication), and use that for authentication.  The actual calls are GET/PUT/POST/DELETE requests with a JSON body when needed.
For an actual stock amount update, you'd make the following PUT request to `/wp-json/wc/v3/products/\<your product's ID\>`, with this JSON body:

```json
{
  "stock_quantity": "500"
}
```

Comment: I know a little about API, I know it's concept. I have two questions. Should I develop a plugin ? and how link external web based system to woocommerce, i.e. I should provide external system with a link or what?

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer your first question (can you program? Do you know how to make HTTP request? Do you know enough about WordPress/Woocommerce?). For your second one, the external system makes HTTP requests to a URL(API endpoint) you provide. You add a JSON payload to it.  Feel free to mark my answer as accepted (I've made a similar plugin for a recent employer)

Comment: I will appriciate, if you can tell me what should I do first. Thanks.

Comment: Via SO is hard but I'll try.  You need to [use Postman for API calls](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/sending-the-first-request/).  If your external system knows the WC product ID's, it'll be easy - you won't need a plugin, just need [WC REST API keys to make a call](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Getting-started-with-the-REST-API).  Test with this GET endpoint: `/wp-json/wc/v3`.  Once this works,try making a POST request to [update](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-a-product) the stock, using the JSON payload in my answer.

Comment: @WebDesign Let me know how it goes, and if you need further help.